# Magento 2: Can't get item ids on sales_order_save_after event

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, event-observer

I need something to do using order item ids when order is created.

I tried `sales_order_place_after` and `sales_order_save_after` events, but unfortunately. Items from `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getAllVisibleItems()` do not have Ids.

Which way should I go to achieve my needs? Also I need to avoid use of checkout controller events, because my code should work on the admin scope too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into `ResourceModel\Order` and `AbstractModel` classes I found event `sales_order_save_commit_after` and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thankyou man! Save my day

Comment: Thank you @spiilmusic, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. you don't need to inject order model

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($orderItems ad $item){
 echo "Order Item ID :".$item->getItemId();
}
```

Let me know if it does not work for you.

**Update Date:- 18th Aug, 2021 Magento ver: 2.4, & I tested in magento version version 2.4**

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$orderId = $order->getId();
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
   $QtyOrdered = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

but we can't debug it in sales_order_save_after event using like echo $variable, print_r($variable) or echo "console.log(".json_encode($variable).")";

If you want to debug it then use logger method(print in log file).

See Below Example code

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Catched event succssfully');
```

I hope this is helps to you... Thank you

---

**Update Date :- 17th Oct, 2022**

for use Logger Method in **Magento version: 2.4.3+**:

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Catched event succssfully');
```

Comment: No, It doesn't work. But I already found solution